# Possibility to use HTTP URL in Velocity Engine

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using  ClasspathResourceLoader in my velocityEngine bean to pick the templates.

Now, I want to change the template location to be picked up from an external http URL say S3 .

Would it be possible to give a **http URL** in resource.loader.class? 
or
Is there any other class which I can use to set the path to http URL?

Currently we are using the below configuration

```
<bean id="velocityEngine"
          class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
            <value>
                resource.loader=class
                class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/URLResourceLoader.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response. I added the below snippet and the solution worked for me.

```
<bean id="velocityEngine"
          class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperty">
          <value>
                resource.loader=class
                class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader
                class.resource.loader.root=https://{URL_Location}
            </value>

        </property> 
    </bean>
```

Hope this answer helps some more people like me :)

Thanks.